# C++ Retrieving the Unicode Code Point in Hex

Tags: c++, unicode, iso-8859-1, unsigned-char

I wanted to do retrieve unicode representation in hex for characters. For an example, for the character €, the value should be 0x0080. I need to do this only for the ISO 8859-1, the first 256 characters of the unicode encoding.  So I used casting to unsigned char in C++ to do this as follows:

```
(unsigned char) normal_character
```

Here, normal_character is of char type.
This has worked so far, however is there any caveats that I should be careful of?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I took the character € as an example. It is not in the ISO 8859-1 charset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO-8859-1 encoding is, by definition, the same as the first 256 codepoints of the Unicode table. So a simple numeric cast is enough. Note, however that Unicode codepoints need at least 32 bits (actually just 21 bits, but... `uint21_t` does not usually exist):

```
char ch_iso88591 = 'a';
uint32_t ch_unicode = (uint32_t)(unsigned char)ch_iso88591;
```

And as you correctly noted in your question, you have to cast it to `unsigned char` because of the posibility `char` being signed.

If the original charset would be anything other than ISO-8859-1 (or ASCII, of course) you'd need to use a table. For example, the Windows-1252 is usually confused with ISO-8859-1, but they are somewhat different (see your € example). If you have Windows-1252 then you **do need** a table. This table is actually quite simple to build, you can copy the values yourself from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (only the values from 0x80 to 0xFF) are needed, because the 0x00-0x7F range is exactly the same).

Answer (score 1):

[ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) does not support the `€` character (Unicode codepoint U+20AC) at all.  There is no mapping defined in [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) for that Unicode codepoint.  [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) does not define any value for byte octet `0x80`, either (most ISO 8859 charsets do not).  That codepoint does map to byte octet `0x80` in a few other charsets, such as [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but does not do so in all charsets.  For example, it maps to `0xA4` instead in [ISO 8859-7:2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-7) and [ISO 8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-15).  So it is not enough to simply truncate that codepoint value to an 8-bit value.  You have to actually map it properly.

Comment: Sorry, I took € as an example. It is not in the ISO 8859-1 set. However, even in the wikipedia article that you have linked shows the hex values in the code page layout table. I checked and the values are the same hex values as I used. Isn't this the case?